# why does sizeof(str) returned diferent output when "str" input into a function as a parameter?

Tags: c, string, sizeof

```
#include<stdio.h>

size_t n(char *str);
int main()
{
    char str[6]="ababd";
    printf("sizeof(str)=%d\n",sizeof(str));
    printf("n(str)=%d\n",n(str));
    return 0;
}
size_t n(char *str)
{
    return sizeof(str);
}
```

Result:

```
sizeof(str)=6
n(str)=8
```

As a new programmer.I know **sizeof(str)=6** is correct.But i don not understand why would **n(str)=8**.I check every document i can find,but i really can not figure out why.I really need help.Thank you!

Comment: You can't pass an array as a parameter.  The thing you are taking the sizeof is a pointer (char *).

Comment: this size of a pointer is fixe because it the size of something pointing to some data it's not the array, pointer isn't an array ! :P

Comment: thank you @stark,@Saren

Comment: For extra fun, try changing the prototype of the `n` function to `size_t n(char str[6])` and see what difference it makes (if any).

Comment: `"%d"` is not the correct format specifier for `size_t`, use `"%zu"`. The compiler may warn about this when you enable compiler warnings (which you should do, use `-Wall -Wextra -Wpedantic` when using gcc).

Comment: Arrays decay to pointer when you use them, in most cases. `sizeof` is one of the  exceptions.

Comment: It is still be ```sizeof(str)=6  n(str)=8```.i think like @12431234123412341234123 said ***Arrays decay to pointer when you use them***.So whether the parameter in '''size_t n()``` be ```char *str``` or ```char str[int]```,the ```str``` will be a pointer in function ```size_t n()```.Thank you! @lan Abbott